# Force --full-history with git log

Tags: git, webstorm

After merges when I do

```
git log <filename.ext>
```

some logs entries are omitted due to History Simplification.

but

```
 git log --full-history <filename.ext>
```

gets me what I want.

Is there a way to force --full-history on git log without all my developers having to perform certain step ?

OR

Is there a way for force this in WebStorm via some configuration (since we can enforce this) ?

OR

Is there a way to do a merge (--no-ff did not work) so that --full-history is not required ?

Comment: My understanding of global is that it is still at the client side i.e. individual developer. It does not change anything in the centrally  repository. As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380765/git-aliases-that-are-stored-in-origin

Comment: That won't work because now I have to ask every developer to perform one of the etspes on every Git project i.e. add .git/config folder and .gitalias. Thanks - I am thinking of finding a create linear commit logs.